# Sending request to update database on browser close with ajax - how to get variable?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am new to php and am trying to update my status variable in a mysql table when the browser is closed. I read in another question that this ajax request is the way to go -

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            url: '../php/changestatus.php'

            });
        });
```

My question is on the php end in changstatus.php, how do I get this variable so I can update my table? It's not a post and doesnt have a variable attached, so what do I do here?

```
session_start();
include("../php/Session.class.php");
$sess = new Session();
$sess->Init();
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE["session"]); 
if($cookie) 
{
$cookie = $_COOKIE["session"];
$account = $sess->Verify($cookie);
}



$closed=$_GET['test'];  //what am I getting?
echo $closed;
```

How can I update a table on browser close?